# How to connect an active sub to mixer

Tags: speakers, subwoofer, system

I'm going to buy a PA system with two 15 inch speakers and an included mixer, and a 15 inch sub. The ones I've chosen are solely because they're in my budget and seem like a good deal for my use purpose. Things that are concerning me are how to connect it all up. So far I can work out that the two speakers will plug into the rear of the mixer, and I'm presuming the sub will plug in through the front where Sub out is, but the plug is different on the mixer and on the actual sub, So would I need to get a special cable, say a XLR to Jack cable, or would that not work? Any advice as to how it would all wire up together would be very welcome.

Here are links to the products I've chosen to buy:

https://www.gear4music.com/PA-DJ-and-Lighting/SubZero-SZPA-815-300W-15-PA-System-with-Microphones-and-Stands/1U2Q

https://www.gear4music.com/PA-DJ-and-Lighting/QTX-QT-Series-15-Active-Subwoofer/25TI

Comment: Your main PA speakers are full-range speakers. Why is it you want to also buy a subwoofer for this configuration? Seems to be superfluous as the main PA speakers can handle the same frequencies as you would be sending to the sub.

Comment: Jordan, there won't be any added sound by simply adding a third bass speaker where you already have two that are perfectly adequate, unless you simply want to implement a system that is bass heavy. Can't recommend that you go down this road.

Comment: Bass-heavy & probably with surprise new phase issues.